# how to use IN with checking the latest id and not displaying the previous id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query, invinfinfoid as the condition. I want to display the highest itemid or the latest itemid (because it is auto increment) and not display the previous itemid.

```sql
SELECT itemid, block_stock, inveninfoid from inventory_movement where inveninfoid IN (71,72,73) order by itemid desc
```

the result

```
itemid   | block_stock | inveninfoid
2313     | 199         | 71
53       | 200         | 73
52       | 200         | 72
51       | 200         | 71
```

and this result i want, Eliminate itemid 51

```
itemid   | block_stock | inveninfoid
2313     | 199         | 71
53       | 200         | 73
52       | 200         | 72
```

Answer (score 0):

You've done an `IN` query against `inveninfoid`(and the `itemid` `2313` has an `inveninfoid` of `71`).

Instead, you want query `IN` against `itemid`:

```
SELECT itemid, block_stock, inveninfoid from inventory_movement
where itemid IN (71,72,73) order by itemid desc
```

Comment: hmm itemid and inveninfoid are different

Comment: I would hope so -- otherwise the column is redundant :)

Comment: I have tried and the results are not as I expected.
thanks u